# how to read LocalTime variable in a Text widget

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

```
  import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
  ...
  private Text textora;
   ...
  LocalTime ora = textora.getLocalTime();
```

I cannot read a LocalTime variable from the Text format for input

Error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The method getLocalTime() is undefined for the 
 type Text
- The method getTime() is undefined for the type 
 Text
```

Comment: `Text` is just plain text and only has a `getText` method. You would have to parse that text to get a date.

Comment: You might also want to look at the SWT `DateTime` control if you want the user to enter a date.

Comment: I didn't want the date, but the time

Comment: `DateTime` does either date or time. For `Text` you will still have to parse the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SWT `Text` control is just plain text and only has a `getText` method to get the string that was entered. To convert the text to `LocalTime` you would have to parse the text:

```java
String timeStr = textora.getString();

LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeStr);
```

`parse` will throw a `DateTimeParseException` exception if the string is not a valid time.

You can also use the SWT `DateTime` control to allow a time to be entered:

```java
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DateTime;

...

DateTime dt = new DateTime(parent, SWT.TIME);

...

LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(dt.getHours(), dt.getMinutes(), dt.getSeconds());
```